# MySQL: Find smallest unused label (number) in range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have several ranges (eg 100 till 200, 201 till 350 etc) in my MySQL data
(row looks like)

```
id (pk)    label (int)    name (string)

1          101            Row1
1          102            Row2
1          104            Row4
1          105            Row5
1          107            Row7
```

Now I want to find a most lowest unused label in a range.
Note: these labels are not keys, just label numbers in an integer field.
When a row is deleted, that label should be available again for a new row with a new ID.

In above example it would be 100.

```
id    label    name

1     100      Row1
1     101      Row1
1     102      Row2
1     104      Row4
1     105      Row5
1     107      Row7
```

In above example it would be 103

```
id    label    name

1     101      Row1
1     102      Row2
1     104      Row4
1     105      Row5
1     107      Row7
```

In above example it would be 100

But with the query

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t1.label + 1) AS number
FROM descriptions t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM descriptions t2 WHERE t2.label = t1.label + 1) AND t1.label IS NOT NULL
AND t1.label >= 100 AND t1.label < 107
ORDER BY t1.label
LIMIT 1
```

It will give me 103 instead of 100 and I need 100

Comment: "When I run the query": what query? I can't follow at all what you are trying to do and what the problem is.

Comment: Is not clearly at all, how can i consider if a label is used or not? Can you give us a functional table, the one you described in the question does not fulfill the conditions.

Comment: See my above edit.

Comment: It's an integer field so numbers only : label  int(6)

Answer (score 2):

One solution: First have a table that contains ALL values. (just needs one column, and then insert rows for all values)

```
CREATE TABLE allnumbers (num MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO allnumbers VALUES ((100),(101),(102),(103),... (400));
```

Then can just do a left join on this

```
SELECT MIN(a.num) FROM allnumbers a LEFT JOIN table t ON (num=label) 
  WHERE a.num BETWEEN 100 AND 200 AND t.label IS NULL;
```

This query in effect finds all allnumber rows, that DONT have a row in table (because of the IS NULL in where) ... but because of the use of aggreigation function (MIN) it includes a virtual 'GROUP BY' to get just one result row.

Comment: A numbers table, the single most useful "meta-table" I ever build :)

Comment: Can be adapted to allow a smaller numbers table by always using the values `0..N` *(In the WHERE clause)* and then including `label = num + X` in the join predicate, to give an effective range of `X..N+X`

Comment: Oh, interesting, never thought of that. Useful trick :) Just need the table with enough 'range' for a single query, rather than all possible values.